# Imported Records not Visible in mySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Imported a SQL file into MySQL using PHPMyAdmin. one of the tables have 469 records the file was successfully imported but in one of the tables, only 319 records are visible. so I tried to insert the missing records manually and get a duplicate record error

> Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry ‘1’ for key ‘PRIMARY’

after which the record is visible but after refresh, the record is not visible again.

the primary key is of type varchar(50)

search is not able to show the primary key record values too. can someone help solve this issue?

Comment: The import file had some duplicate values for the primary key column, they don't get imported.

Comment: no, I have checked it, it doesn't have duplicate values. the primary key is a set of variable names

Comment: The database doesn't lie, it wouldn't say "Duplicate entry" if there weren't a duplicate.

Comment: yes, that is why I am asking how to get it to be displayed and why it is not getting displayed. what is there in the SQL file was successfully imported. so it has to be there and since I am not able to add and the error message clearly shows that it is there. but it is not displayed.

Comment: Have you tried repairing the table, maybe there's a problem with the index.

Comment: checked the database and found some tables missing and I guess that there have been issues during import. So the only option is to reimport the complete database and work afresh.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the table you are having issues with is using the incorrect column as the key for that table. The key has to be unique for every row in that table and there are multiple rows with the value of ‘1’ for that column so it will not import. See if you can pick the key column while importing that contains unique values like a loan number or ssn.

Comment: Yes, the variable name is the primary key and there are no duplicates.